# Ivy: sort candidates by most recently used

Tags: ivy, sorting

I'm coming from Helm to Ivy just to try it out, and one thing I miss greatly from Helm is how the default candidate when hitting `M-x` is whatever the last command was.

Is there some way to sort Ivy's results by most-recently used?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but might help: `Ivy re-uses the following packages if they are installed: avy, amx or smex, flx, and wgrep.` So if you install smex you will have your last used commands at the top.

Comment: I would additionally suggest ivy-prescient(https://github.com/raxod502/prescient.el).

Comment: @Aquaactress That worked. Thank you! If you turn it into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Update 2022-11-21: the best answer is to use Daniel Mendler's Vertico package with Consult, Marginalia, and Orderless :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using [ivy-prescient](https://github.com/raxod502/prescient.el). It is a package that provides sorting and filtering for ivy.

After installing it, you enable it with `ivy-prescient-mode`.

For more details on it's usage see [its usage README section](https://github.com/raxod502/prescient.el#usage).